# Why does ConcurrentHashMap not store the size of the map in a AtomicInteger?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, volatile, concurrenthashmap

In the JavaDoc for the `size()` method in `ConcurrentHashMap` it states:

"Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods including `size`, `isEmpty`, and `containsValue` are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads."

I know that in most concurrent applications maps are essentially moving targets therefore it is not that common to need the value returned by `size()` method to be guaranteed to be correct. But in my case I actually do need it to be correct(not a stale value).

Seen as I really do not want to lock the whole table for each `size()` call, my question is why does `ConcurrentHashMap` not just store the size of the table in an `AtomicInteger` field, which gets updated as part of a `put()` or `remove()` operation? If it did then the write to the size field would always be atomic and (due to the fact that `AtomicInteger` stores its value in a volatile field) then any reads from the size field would be return the most recently updated version of the field...

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: So you "actually need it to be correct" but "do not want to lock the whole table for each size() call", so the value can change while you are getting it.  And immediately after it.  I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "correct", since it seems you have defined the problem so that it is not constant even during the get operation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are missing something. Imagine 10 threads performing updates, and the eleventh regularly determining the size of the map.

The numbers the 11th thread reads totally depends on the execution timing of the 10 other threads. Using an atomic integer would not help here.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know why a volatile size (e.g. via an AtomicInteger) was not used.  So the 11th would not need to determine the size, it would just return the value of the volatile size field.

Comment: @Jose Martinez: because a `volatile` size field would not change the specified behavior. This answer explains that.

Comment: @JoseMartinez, If you ask for `map.size()` while other threads are concurrently adding and removing entries from the map, the best you can possibly hope for is that the return value will be the actual size of the map _at some point in the recent past_.  It is not reasonable to expect that the map still will be that same size by the time you _use_ the return value to make a decision.

Comment: @jameslarge that still does not tackle the main question why AtomicInteger or a volatile size is not used.  I'm not saying there isn't a good reason, I think I know the reason, just that this answer does not provide a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

As [ruediste explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700758/2711488), the size information is pointless, if you have ongoing concurrent updates. You may get the old value, the new value, or an arbitrary in-between value in case of multiple updates.

This has nothing to do with the question whether the value is stored in an atomic integer or not. But the whole point about `ConcurrentHashMap` is to allow *concurrent* updates.

“Concurrent” means there is no time relationship nor order of actions. When a thread attempts to insert a value while another one attempts to remove a value, there is a time relationship *only if* they are accessing the same key. In that case the removing thread can use the result to tell whether an insertion happened before the removal or not. In all other cases, the threads act independently.

When querying the size at the same time you may get the old size, the old size plus one or the old size minus one (in case the initial state wasn’t empty). If you get a value different from the old size, you may use it to deduce whether the insertion or the removal happened first, and come to a wrong conclusion. A different thread using `containsKey` at the same time to detect if either key is present might perceive a different order of these actions. That’s what “no ordering” or “no time relationship” implies.

Maintaining an atomic integer size value wouldn’t change anything. There is still a point where a thread has modified the map’s content but not the size field yet. And there might be an arbitrary number of threads right at this point. But forcing all threads to update a single atomic integer would reduce concurrency drastically. While an atomic integer is faster than a `synchronized` block, it’s still a kind of synchronization action which suffers from high contention. So it would reduce performance without solving any problem.

Comment: great thanks. This seems to be a potential solution to my problem, claiming 0(1) atomic snapshots. en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrie

Answer (score 3):

Fact #1:  Updating a single `size` field has the potential to be a concurrency bottleneck, whether it is implemented as a `volatile int`, an `AtomicInteger` or something else.

Fact #2:  In the vast majority of use-cases for `ConcurrentHashMap`, the `size()` method is not useful to the application because it only tells you the size at a particular instant.  (If that.  The javadoc does not actually specify what `size()` will return in the face of concurrent updates. )

If we assume that `size()` is unlikely to be called, then introducing a potential concurrency bottleneck into update operations in case it is called seems like a bad idea to me.  I'm guessing that the author (Doug Lea) had similar thoughts.

Comment: I agree with this answer over the other ones.